# Placeholder text in search box is black instead of white

Tags: bug, status-norepro, design

It appears the "search" placeholder text in the search boxes (on both the main site and meta) are black instead of white, making them hard to read. However, when you begin to type a search, the text turns white, like it should.

(I repro'd this on Chrome 13.0.782.112 and Safari 5.1 (7534.48.3), both on OS X 10.7.)

[image]

Comment: Repro'd on Chrome 13.0.782.112 beta-m.  Could not repro on IE 8 or FF 5.0.1.  All on Windows XP.

Comment: Could not repro on FF 4.0.1, IE 9.0.8112.16421 or SeaMonkey 2.0.14, repro'd on Chrome 13.0.782.112 m and Safari 5.0.5 (7533.21.1), all on Windows Vista.

Comment: Hmm, possibly a WebKit bug or aberration then.

Comment: Yeah, I suspect it's WebKit-related as well.

Answer (score 1):

WebKit doesn't seem to inherit the input's `color` value for the placeholder text (now that the search fields use the [HTML5 placeholder attribute](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec/Overview.html#the-placeholder-attribute)), so it needs a little extra coaxing in the form of

```
#hsearch .textbox::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

I think WebKit is a bit wrong in requiring this, but since the expected behaviour isn't particularly well-defined (that I know of), it's currently necessary.

**Edit**: It looks like Chrome and Safari added a default `::-webkit-input-placeholder` definition to their user agent stylesheets with `color:#A9A9A9;`, so this is now fixed in the sense that the placeholder is at least reasonably legible.

Answer (score 0):

I marked this as norepro because 3 years on, it looks like it's no longer an issue.